# plugin DataTables jquery : how display formated Date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Among my source properties , I have a column created by doing javascript code

```
 var col_date =   new Date(timestamp)
```

It display me a column with text formated like this : 
*Sun Feb 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)*

I would like to display it  in MM/DD/YYYY or YYYY/MM/DD formar ( whatever , I want it short and easily readable)

Do you know how to do it please?

Comment: Can you use [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Also Check Out The Moment Timezone Lib.. It's Legit

Comment: transforming the response's individual dates into html strings before giving to DT is the simplest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DataTables, you can modify the value shown in the table in two ways:

1. change it in the source data, or
2. leave the source data alone but tell DataTables to render it differently

It sounds like #2 is what you are looking for. See the [reference documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html#) that includes an example.

Another possible example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654864/datatables-how-do-i-show-only-date-rather-than-datetime).